# 2D Ball Movement for Windows Store App in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, visual-studio-2013, physics

First of all, im totally new to C# and I have to work on an Windows Store App for a study project. 
I decided to develop an App, where you have to keep a ball in the air (with a paddle at the bottom of the field, nearly the same as in the classic pong game), which was really stupid cause I literally have no idea how to do this.

My code looks like this at the moment:

```
void Timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {


        Rect rectBall = new Rect(BallTransform.TranslateX, BallTransform.TranslateY, RectBall.ActualWidth, RectBall.ActualHeight);
        Rect rectPaddle = new Rect(PaddleTransform.TranslateX, PaddleTransform.TranslateY, RectPaddle.ActualWidth, RectPaddle.ActualHeight);

        rectPaddle.Intersect(rectBall);


        int counter = 0;
        Score.Text = ("Score: " + counter);

        if (rectPaddle.IsEmpty == true)
        {
            BallTransform.TranslateY += 20;
        }
        if (BallTransform.TranslateY - 50 > PaddleTransform.TranslateY)
        {
            BallTransform.TranslateY -= 20;
            Result.Text = ("Game Over!");

        }
        //if (rectPaddle.IsEmpty == false)
        //{
        //    counter += 1;
        //    BallTransform.TranslateY -= 20;
        //    Score.Text = ("Score: " + counter);

        //}

    }

    void CoreWindow_KeyDown(Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow sender, Windows.UI.Core.KeyEventArgs args)
    {
        switch (args.VirtualKey)
        {
            case Windows.System.VirtualKey.A:
                PaddleTransform.TranslateX -= 40;
                break;
            case Windows.System.VirtualKey.D:
                PaddleTransform.TranslateX += 40;
                break;
            case Windows.System.VirtualKey.Left:
                PaddleTransform.TranslateX -= 40;
                break;
            case Windows.System.VirtualKey.Right:
                PaddleTransform.TranslateX += 40;
                break;
            default:
                break;

        }
    }

    private void Grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PaddleTransform.TranslateY = Grid.ActualHeight - RectPaddle.ActualHeight - 20;
        PaddleTransform.TranslateX = (Grid.ActualWidth / 2) - RectPaddle.ActualWidth;
        BallTransform.TranslateX = (Grid.ActualWidth / 2) - RectBall.ActualWidth;


        DispatcherTimer Timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        Timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(100);
        Timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
        Timer.Start();
    }

}
```

}

I know that this is not really much, and it doesn´t really do anything than letting the ball fall down, if it touches the paddle, it just stays where it is and if it misses the paddle, it´s "game over".

My biggest problem is, to find out how to let the ball jump up again after falling on the paddle, and give it different bouncing directions after doing this. Also I don´t know how I should handle the speed of the ball.

I´d be really happy if someone could explain me what i should do.

Thanks in advance!

PS: I read a lot of "Pong" and "Ball physic" tutorials, but they didn´t really help me.

Comment: An impact with the paddle at the bottom of the screen is simply a reversal of the vertical component of the velocity of the ball. e.g. if the ball is moving with velocity X=10 and Y=10 (representing a diagonal downward movement), collision with the paddle will change the velocity to X=10, Y=-10 (a diagonal upward movement).

Answer (score 0):

A simple way of doing this is to keep track of the velocity of the ball in a separate variable, and using that to update its translation.

ie something along the lines of this:  (example is not complete, but i hope you get the gist of it)

```
float BallXVel = 10;
float BallYVel = 20;

void Timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
    //always move the ball.
    BallTransform.TranslateX += BallXVel;
    BallTransform.TranslateY += BallYVel;

    //bounce the ball up if it hits the paddle and is not already moving up
    if (!rectPaddle.IsEmpty && BallYVel > 0)
    {
       BallYVel = 0-BallYVel;
    }

    if (BallTransform.TranslateY - 50 > PaddleTransform.TranslateY)
    {
           BallTransform.TranslateY -= 20;
           Result.Text = ("Game Over!");
    }

}
```

Comment: please note that this in no way a complete example, and propbably not the exact optimal way of going about this, but i want OP to figure it out. understanding is half the battle.